# replace file name have multiple extensions in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an issue while uploading documents have multiple periods. For example if I upload a file having an extension of ammu.gopu.docx. I would like to replace that as ammu_gopu.docx, means to preserve the extension and replace the file name with undescore.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what your asking.  Beware - If your file name also appears in the path it will also be updated.

```
Dim fullPath As String = "C:\Test\My.File.Name.txt"
Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath)
fullPath = fullPath.Replace(fileName, fileName.Replace("."c, "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [System.IO.Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) method.

Comment: This takes the extension . I would like te replace periods(.) with undescore(-).                                                          Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filePath = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath) & _
           IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath).Replace("."c, "_"c) & _ 
           "." & IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath)
```